# How to import a CVS file into a MongoDB using reactive way?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, project-reactor, reactive

As the title says, I am trying to read a cvs file that contains thousands of ip addresses to their respective country. I want to import the cvs file into a MongoDB using WebFlux. I haven't been able to find any resources on how to do this. I have come across Spring Batch but I don't believe it supports WebFlux.

One way I thought of achieving this is just read the CVS file, parse the file, create DTO with values then save it into the database, however, I worry about performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring WebFlux is the alternative to Spring MVC module. It is not suitable for data processing. So if you want to solve your problem, use this way:

> One way I thought of achieving this is just read the CVS file, parse the file, create DTO with values then save it into the database, however, I worry about performance.

And "reactive way" won't be faster than batch processing just because it's "reactive".

Comment: For future people, I didn't realize Spring Batch is included in WebFlux. You can insert a collection of objects as a batch. You don't have to do it singularly. 
"return template.insert(collection, Data.class);" returns a Flux<Data> which you can subscribe and do whatever to.